# Regex super slow in Lazarus. What should I do?

Tags: regex, delphi, lazarus

I am trying to run a RE in my Lazarus application on a SynEdit component but it is way too slow, even freezing my application. My file is quite large (1.5gb) but when I RE it using Sublime Text, it process everything real quick (matter of seconds).
So what I am doing is loading my CSV file to my SynEdit component and processing the RE from there. Something like this:

```
mySynEdit.LoadFromFile('myFile.CSV');
...
var
rx:Tregexpr;
res:String;
button.click...
begin
  rx:=TRegexpr.create;
  rx.expression:='myRE';
  try
    res:=rx.replace(mySynEdit.Text, 'myReplaceText', true);
    mySynEdit.text:=res;
  finally
    rx.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Any clue of why it is taking so long to process this file? Should I use another "faster" lib? So please help me to speed up this process.

Thank you as always
J

Comment: What is the regex? Can you repro this on regex101.com?

Comment: Is it synedit that is so slow fetching a certain line, or the regex searching the line? IOW, it doesn#t have to be the regex. Try the same with text in an easier to access format, e.g. a TStringList (or similar) and see if it is slow too. If not, it was Synedit. Note that 1.5GB might cause text to be loaded in and out of main memory, which can be very slow. In that case, a different approach (like a memory mapped file) might be required.

Comment: SynEdit is a syntax highlighter.  You're feeding it a 1.5GB text file.  This immediately makes us suspect that the time hog here is the enormous task of parsing that 1.5GB text file for syntax tokens.  Definitely agree with @RudyVelthuis - you need to test this with a more sane container for your text.  Profile (or even just set a breakpoint) - find out where your bottleneck is.

Comment: How about responding to some of the comments you've had?

Comment: Aside: your use of try finally is wrong. Always place try immediately after resource is acquired

Answer (score 0):

You process your search on a copy because `mySynEdit.Text` is a getter that joins each line to a string (hence it allocates and moves a lot to build the `.Text`). So you might see a performance improvment if you search and replace line by line:

```
for line in mySynEdit.Lines do begin
  //
end;
```

Actually the text displayed in a Synedit doesn't exist as a big contiguous memory chunck. Everything is split by line.

that said, if a match starts on a line and ends on the next one it won't be detected.

Also note that if you're using the Lazarus SynEdit fork, some helpers exist to search on a SynEdit, incl. using some RegExes, in TCustomSynEdit:

```
function SearchReplace(const ASearch, AReplace: string; AOptions: TSynSearchOptions): integer;
function SearchReplaceEx(const ASearch, AReplace: string; AOptions: TSynSearchOptions; AStart: TPoint): integer;
```

Comment: Hey Guys, I want to thank you all for helping me. So far I have tried to solve the problem by not using any visual component. I created a Thread in which I added a TStringList to load and process the Regex. But still too slow. 
@Nested type, I am trying to use the SearchReplaceEx in my SynEdit but it does not accept the [ssoOptions]... like this: 
SynEdit1.SearchReplaceEx('myRegex', 'ReplaceText', [ssoReplaceAll, ssoRegExpr], Point(1,1));
I am using FPC 2.6.4 - Lazarus 1.4

Comment: @jufau not sharing an MCVE with us makes it impossible to help you. Why won't you do that?